# Can't set up remote access on chrome remote desktop

Tags: ssh, google-chrome, remote-desktop, chrome-extension

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and while I can download chrome remote desktop and access my machine using the Remote Support section and typing in the code, I do not see any ability to add my device in the remote access section. I can't add my device and the two devices are my two other computers that I have set it up on (one mac one windows).

[image: What I see]

Answer (score 12):

Basically, the solution is: `mkdir ~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop`

Comment: It works for 20.04 too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dron4K can you please guide m how did you resolve this isse? I am also using ubunto 20.04. For  both remote access and remote set up via ssh not working. I want to access my ubunto os from macbook. I installed .deb file i face the following systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop
● chrome-remote-desktop.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit chrome-remote-desktop.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)