# How can I "Turn On" Chrome remote desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, chrome-extension

So I have Chrome Remote Desktop installed in Windows on 2 of my machines, and I want to set it up in Ubuntu as well (so that I can easily access my machine at home from work etc). So I went to https://remotedesktop.google.com/access as I did in Windows and chose to set it up. It downloaded the .deb and I installed it. But when I go back to that link after installing, I expected to see an option to "Turn On" and put the machine name and pin in.

Instead, I got this:
[image: remote desktop access screen]

I checked in terminal, and it seems to be running fine:
[image: chrome remote desktop in terminal]

So why am I not getting an option to turn it on (and set it up)? Seems the extension in Chrome has no options available either.

for the record, this is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 and chrome is up to date etc.

Comment: Hey there - did you ever find a solution to this?!

Comment: No, seems like a huge bug!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261005/cant-set-up-remote-access-on-chrome-remote-desktop, this one works for me. Create the folder and the turn on button shows up.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Its a bug for the chrome remote desktop installer not creating its own config folder. So simply create it via `mkdir ~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop`, refresh your chrome, and the "turn on" section will show up.

Comment: Thank you! Just worked for me on an Ubuntu 20.04 fresh install.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where the "turn on" button is

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy just open the extension's management, or, currently it's on this URL https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/ (yes it's not a local address) ... if you really need a screen - https://pasteboard.co/lW4m5NTol0Ie.png (assuming you've installed the extension in the first place)

Comment: I wasn't seeing that. Installer must not have worked, even when I created the folder. Anyway problem solved now, I replaced the computer with a Windows 11 one.