# Cannot “Turn On” Chrome remote desktop in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I have installed Chrome Remote Desktop in my Windows machine, and am trying to so the same in Ubuntu 20.04 machine. After following the instruction (https://remotedesktop.google.com/access) I was able to install Chrome Remote Desktop. After this, in Windows I saw the setup screen to enter hostname and pin number, but it didn't show up in Ubuntu.

I found the following post ([How can I "Turn On" Chrome remote desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265668/how-can-i-turn-on-chrome-remote-desktop-in-ubuntu-20-04/1315706#1315706)), and did what it suggests, creating a directory under ~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop. But this time it didn't solve the problem. I checked the program status by systemctl, and it says active.

It seems user interface of the chrome remote desktop is updated since this post. I believe it is another bug on Chrome Remote Desktop installer (with new user interface). Any suggestion of alternative option is appreciated. E.g., a method of configuring host and pin # by hand without going through the installer, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file dependency was messed up.

```
$ sudo apt-get install xbase-clients 
$ sudo apt-get install python3-psutil
```

I got error message, so did the below as it said:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Then at downloaded directory,

```
$ sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
```

Then I created a directory under ~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop.

After reboot (I did it for sure), access
https://remotedesktop.google.com/access
Then the set up message for hostname and pin # showed up.