# chrome remote desktop connection disconnected immdiately

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I installed `chrome remote desktop` in Ubuntu 18.04.

First issue, I can't add a new device which solved by:

[Can't set up remote access on chrome remote desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261005/cant-set-up-remote-access-on-chrome-remote-desktop)

The current issue, the connection is always disconnected when trying to connect from other devices.

When login ( enter the pin code ), it will show a session selection screen.
Whatever I choose, both get an end connection immediately.

The options are:

1. (default) Launch the default XSession.
2. Ubuntu This session logs you into Ubuntu.

PS.

1. The pin code is correct.
2. If I use `Remote Support` function which generated the one-time connection code, it works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user needs to log out first in the local machine.

Comment: How does the local machine user log in after that? 
Even after my remote session is disconnected, I can't login from the local machine. 
It acts like I'm still remote connected to the sever.

Comment: The remote session needs to logout also.

Comment: Is there a way for a remote user to force out everyone else when a local user is logged in?